# Can I connect a cloudant db to watson iot from the command line on bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, cloudant, watson-iot

the documentation on bluemix shows how to connect a cloudantdb to the watson iot service using the web interface (https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-parti/#r_step3)

Is is possible to do this using only the (cf) bluemix command line client (so that I can automate/script the process)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is not a way to script the binding of a service for Historical data.  It must be a human initiated action which requires the user to be signed in to Bluemix and IoT Platform to obtain the service credentials from Bluemix.